# Getting a white flash between page loads in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm a beginner web developer who is making a Laravel project for a cumulative school assignment. I recently ran into an issue I can't seem to find a solution for. I had everything running smoothly before I decided to experiment with Bootstrap and ended up installing Laravel's JavaScript & CSS Scaffolding (composer require laravel/ui) and the bootstrap scaffolding (php artisan ui bootstrap)...I am now realizing you should not do this partway through an in progress project.

After the installation I noticed a white flash occurring every time I clicked on a link to a new page. My gut tells me it has something to do with conflicting code added by the scaffolding. I've done my best to trace back my steps and remove anything the scaffolding added, but I can't seem to get the flash to go away. Does anyone have an idea what might be causing it? I'd really appreciate any advice. I'm hoping to not have to copy over my work to a fresh laravel project.

Comment: Are you using source control such as git? You could easily restore the composer.json and composer.lock files to how they were before. You could also then try renaming your `vendor` directory to something else like vendor2, then do a fresh composer install from your composer files. If you don't have source control, you could probably go into your composer.json file manually and remove the laravel/ui from it provided you don't break the JSON syntax, then with no vendor directory you can composer install, etc. You might also try checking logs for some hints

Comment: Also "white flash" could be caused by either the frontend or backend such as during a redirect. You might try testing your site such as through CURL and get a better idea regarding the content being returned, if it's a header or javascript etc.